Altium schematic: component comment color getting overridden
I have a problem with setting the color of a comment for certain components in a schematic drawing. I want to be able to override the default color by some other, but it keeps getting overridden by some config.
The error is like this: I select the comment I want to change, select the desired color, deselect the comment and the color changes back to the original color. I've already checked that the "Override library primitive" option in Tools>Preferences>Defaults>Comment is checked; I don't know if there is any other option I need to enable.


This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

It's not a Comment, it's a designator. Might help to use the correct term for further troubleshooting.
